My buy/sell sign Messages are delayed by 1 week compared to tradingview
Even after using GPT, I couldn't quite figure out the exact reason why my code isn't working as expected.
Here's what I'm trying to achieve:
For Weekly Signals: My goal is to receive buy and sell signals immediately after the closing value of each Friday. I want these signals to be generated right after the market closes at the end of the week, so I can act on them without any delay.
For Monthly Signals: Similarly, I want to receive buy and sell signals right after the closing value of each month. These signals should be triggered immediately after the market closes on the last trading day of the month.
However, despite my efforts, the code doesn't seem to be functioning correctly. Instead of getting the signals promptly after the weekly or monthly close, there appears to be a delay. I'm not sure why this is happening, and I haven't been able to pinpoint the exact issue.
The aim is to have the signals reflect the most recent data as soon as it's available, but the current implementation is falling short of that.
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import requests
import pandas_ta as ta
import numpy as np
from time import sleep
import warnings

warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)

t2_list = ["BINHO.IS","AVOD.IS","ACSEL.IS","ADGYO.IS","AFYON.IS","AKCNS.IS","ATEKS.IS","AKSGY.IS","AKSA.IS","AKSEN.IS","ALBRK.IS","ALCTL.IS","ALKA.IS","ALKIM.IS","ALVES.IS","ASUZU.IS","ANELE.IS",
"ARDYZ.IS","ARENA.IS","ARTMS.IS","ARZUM.IS","ASGYO.IS","ASELS.IS","ATAGY.IS","ATAKP.IS","ATATP.IS","AVPGY.IS","BNTAS.IS","BANVT.IS","BARMA.IS","BASGZ.IS","BAYRK.IS","BRKSN.IS","BEYAZ.IS","BIMAS.IS",
"BIOEN.IS","BRLSM.IS","BOBET.IS","BORSK.IS","BORLS.IS","BURCE.IS","BURVA.IS","BUCIM.IS","CATES.IS","CLEBI.IS","CELHA.IS","CEMAS.IS","CEMTS.IS","CMBTN.IS","COSMO.IS","CWENE.IS","DAPGM.IS","DARDL.IS",
"DGATE.IS","DESA.IS","DESPC.IS","DITAS.IS","DMRGD.IS","DOFER.IS","DGNMO.IS","ARASE.IS","DOAS.IS","DOGUB.IS","EBEBK.IS","EDATA.IS","EGGUB.IS","EGPRO.IS","EKOS.IS","EKSUN.IS","ELITE.IS","ENJSA.IS","ERCB.IS"
,"EREGL.IS","ERSU.IS","ESCOM.IS","TEZOL.IS","EYGYO.IS","FADE.IS","FMIZP.IS","FONET.IS","FORMT.IS","FRIGO.IS","FZLGY.IS","GEDZA.IS","GENTS.IS","GEREL.IS","GMTAS.IS","GESAN.IS","GOLTS.IS","GOODY.IS",
"GRTRK.IS","GUBRF.IS","GRSEL.IS","HATSN.IS","HKTM.IS","HUBVC.IS","HUNER.IS","ICUGS.IS","IDGYO.IS","IHEVA.IS","IHLGM.IS","IHGZT.IS","IHYAY.IS","INGRM.IS","INTEM.IS","INVES.IS","ISKPL.IS","IEYHO.IS",
"ISDMR.IS","IZINV.IS","IZFAS.IS","JANTS.IS","KFEIN.IS","KLKIM.IS","KLSER.IS","KRDMA.IS","KRDMB.IS","KRDMD.IS","KARSN.IS","KRTEK.IS","KARYE.IS","KTLEV.IS","KATMR.IS","KAYSE.IS","KRVGD.IS","KZBGY.IS",
"KCAER.IS","KNFRT.IS","KONTR.IS","KONYA.IS","KONKA.IS","KGYO.IS","KRGYO.IS","KRPLS.IS","KOTON.IS","KOPOL.IS","KRSTL.IS","KRONT.IS","KUTPO.IS","KBORU.IS","LILAK.IS","LMKDC.IS","LINK.IS","LOGO.IS",
"LKMNH.IS","MAKTK.IS","MANAS.IS","MTRKS.IS","MAVI.IS","MEDTR.IS","MEGAP.IS","MEKAG.IS","MNDRS.IS","MERCN.IS","MERKO.IS","MHRGY.IS","MIATK.IS","MIPAZ.IS","MPARK.IS","MOBTL.IS","MNDTR.IS","EGEPO.IS",
"NTGAZ.IS","NETAS.IS","NIBAS.IS","NUHCM.IS","OBAMS.IS","ODAS.IS","ONCSM.IS","ORGE.IS","OYAKC.IS","OYLUM.IS","OZRDN.IS","OZSUB.IS","PNLSN.IS","PARSN.IS","PASEU.IS","PSGYO.IS","PATEK.IS","PCILT.IS",
"PGSUS.IS","PEKGY.IS","PENGD.IS","PENTA.IS","PETUN.IS","PNSUT.IS","PKART.IS","PLTUR.IS","POLHO.IS","POLTK.IS","RALYH.IS","RODRG.IS","RUBNS.IS","SAFKR.IS","SANEL.IS","SANFM.IS","SANKO.IS","SASA.IS",
"SEKUR.IS","SELEC.IS","SELGD.IS","SELVA.IS","SRVGY.IS","SILVR.IS","SNGYO.IS","SMRTG.IS","SMART.IS","SOKE.IS","SONME.IS","SUNTK.IS","SURGY.IS","SUWEN.IS","TABGD.IS","TKFEN.IS","TDGYO.IS","TUKAS.IS",
"TMSN.IS","TUPRS.IS","TUREX.IS","MARBL.IS","THYAO.IS","TRILC.IS","PRKAB.IS","ULUSE.IS","ULUUN.IS","USAK.IS","VAKKO.IS","VBTYZ.IS","VRGYO.IS","VERUS.IS","VESTL.IS","VESBE.IS","YATAS.IS","YYLGD.IS",
"YEOTK.IS","YUNSA.IS","ZEDUR.IS","ZRGYO.IS","AAPL"
]

dates_diff = {0:3, 1:4, 2:5, 3:6, 4:7, 5:1, 6:2}

# Define Discord webhook URLs
webhook_url_weekly = "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/1233174956033183774/6bPY4dWv65Hl7WuSz8iProaimirFhXZ2uPoAwRrxhiA9cKq8I9b9sx7pS31pIWTuJakN1"
webhook_url_monthly = "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/1233175422733127793/4Vh5eYiEnPRfvvscJPCVC8UAt2eEgr8IWB_Vp3yGA55sIb6wfKbId0XnZIgKePJqlDoD1"

# Define function to send Discord webhook
def webhook_discord(url, date_str, signal, ticker, crosspoint=None):
    if crosspoint:
        content = f"{date_str}, {signal} signal for stock {ticker} at price {crosspoint}"
    else:
        content = f"{date_str}, {signal} signal for stock {ticker}"

    data = {
        "content": content
    }
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    response = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)
    if response.status_code != 204:
        print(f"Failed to send Discord webhook: {response.status_code} - {response.text}")

# Download historical stock data for weekly intervals
def download_weekly_data(ticker, start_date, end_date):
    stock_data = yf.download(ticker, start=start_date, end=end_date, interval="1wk")
    return stock_data

# Download historical stock data for monthly intervals
def download_monthly_data(ticker, start_date, end_date):
    stock_data = yf.download(ticker, start=start_date, end=end_date, interval="1mo")
    return stock_data

# Calculate MACD and Signal Line
# def calculate_macd(df, short_window=12, long_window=26, signal_window=9):
#     # Calculate Short-term EMA
#     df['ShortDEMA'] = df['Close'].ewm(span=short_window, adjust=False).mean()

#     # Calculate Long-term EMA
#     df['LongDEMA'] = df['Close'].ewm(span=long_window, adjust=False).mean()

#     # Calculate MACD line
#     df['MACD_DEMA'] = df['ShortDEMA'] - df['LongDEMA']

#     # Calculate Signal line (9-period EMA of MACD)
#     df['Signal_Line'] = df['MACD_DEMA'].ewm(span=signal_window, adjust=False).mean()

#     return df


def calculate_macd_dema(df, short_window=12, long_window=26, signal_window=9):
    # Calculate Short-term DEMA
    def ema(series, span):
        ta_ema = ta.ema(series, span)
        return ta_ema

    def dema(series, span):
        ema1 = ema(series, span)
        ema2 = ema(ema1, span)
        return 2 * ema1 - ema2

    # Parameters
    sma = 12
    lma = 26
    tsp = 9

    # Calculate DEMAs
    df['DEMAfast'] = dema(df['Close'], sma)
    df['DEMAslow'] = dema(df['Close'], lma)


    # Calculate MACD Line and Signal Line

    df['MACD_DEMA'] = df['DEMAfast'] - df['DEMAslow']
    #print(df['MACD_DEMA'])
    df['Signal_Line'] = dema(df['MACD_DEMA'], tsp)

    df['MACDZeroLag'] = df['MACD_DEMA'] - df['Signal_Line']
    return df

# Check for MACD and Signal Line crossovers
def check_crossovers(df):
    # crossovers = []
    # for i in range(1, len(df)):

    #     if df['MACD_DEMA'].iloc[i] > df['Signal_Line'].iloc[i] and df['MACD_DEMA'].iloc[i - 1] <= df['Signal_Line'].iloc[i - 1]:
    #         crosspoint = df['Close'].iloc[i]
    #         crossovers.append((df.index[i], "Buy", crosspoint))

    #     elif df['MACD_DEMA'].iloc[i] < df['Signal_Line'].iloc[i] and df['MACD_DEMA'].iloc[i - 1] >= df['Signal_Line'].iloc[i - 1]:
    #         crosspoint = df['Close'].iloc[i]
    #         crossovers.append((df.index[i], "Sell", crosspoint))
    #     else:
    #         crossovers.append((df.index[i], "Neutral", None))  # None when there's no crosspoint
    df_macd_dema_1 = df['MACD_DEMA']
    df_macd_dema_2 = df['MACD_DEMA'].shift(1)

    df_signal_1 = df['Signal_Line']
    df_signal_2 = df['Signal_Line'].shift(1)

    df['Crossover'] = np.where((df_macd_dema_1 > df_signal_1) & (df_macd_dema_2 <= df_signal_2), 'Buy',
                           np.where((df_macd_dema_1 < df_signal_1) & (df_macd_dema_2 >= df_signal_2), 'Sell', 'Neutral'))

    df['Crosspoint'] = np.where( (df['Crossover']=='Buy') | (df['Crossover']=='Sell'), df['Close'], None)


    return df

# Format data for TradingView-like output
def format_tradingview_output(df):
    tradingview_data = pd.DataFrame({
        'Date': df.index,
        'Open': df['Open'],
        'High': df['High'],
        'Low': df['Low'],
        'Close': df['Close'],
        #'Volume': df['Volume'],
        #'ShortDEMA': df['ShortDEMA'],
        #'LongDEMA': df['LongDEMA'],
        'MACD_DEMA': df['MACD_DEMA'],
        'Signal_Line': df['Signal_Line'],
        #'MACD_DEMA': df['LigneMACDZeroLag'],
        #'Signal_Line': df['Lignesignal'],
        'Crossover': df['Crossover'], #[crossover[1] for crossover in crossovers],
        'Crosspoint': df['Crosspoint']
    })
    tradingview_data.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    return tradingview_data


# Main function
def main():
    # Define end date as today and start date as beginning of 2024
    end_date = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    start_date = datetime(2018, 1, 1).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)  # Display all rows

    for stock in t2_list:

        # Download stock data for both intervals
        stock_data_weekly = download_weekly_data(stock, start_date, end_date)
        stock_data_weekly['Open'] = stock_data_weekly['Open'].round(2)
        stock_data_weekly['Close'] = stock_data_weekly['Close'].round(2)
        stock_data_weekly['High'] = stock_data_weekly['High'].round(2)
        stock_data_weekly['Low'] = stock_data_weekly['Low'].round(2)

        stock_data_monthly = download_monthly_data(stock, start_date, end_date)
        stock_data_monthly['Open'] = stock_data_monthly['Open'].round(2)
        stock_data_monthly['Close'] = stock_data_monthly['Close'].round(2)
        stock_data_monthly['High'] = stock_data_monthly['High'].round(2)
        stock_data_monthly['Low'] = stock_data_monthly['Low'].round(2)
        print(stock, len(stock_data_weekly), len(stock_data_monthly))
        sleep(2)
        if len(stock_data_weekly) >= 71:

            #stock_data_weekly = calculate_macd(stock_data_weekly)
            stock_data_weekly = calculate_macd_dema(stock_data_weekly)
            #print(stock_data_weekly.iloc[:, -8:])
            stock_data_weekly = check_crossovers(stock_data_weekly)

            # tradingview_data_weekly = format_tradingview_output(stock_data_weekly)

            for i, r in stock_data_weekly.iterrows():
                sent_date = i + timedelta(days = 6)
                date_str = sent_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')  # Adjust format as needed
                previous_friday = datetime.now() - timedelta(days = dates_diff[datetime.now().weekday()] + 1 )
                pre_previous_friday =previous_friday - timedelta(days = 7 )
                if r['Crossover'] != 'Neutral' and i>pre_previous_friday and i<previous_friday:
                    #pass
                    print('weekly', date_str, stock, r['Crossover'])
                    webhook_discord(webhook_url_weekly, date_str, r['Crossover'], stock, r['Crosspoint'])
                    sleep(5)

        if len(stock_data_monthly) >= 71:

            stock_data_monthly = calculate_macd_dema(stock_data_monthly)
            stock_data_monthly = check_crossovers(stock_data_monthly)

            for i , r in stock_data_monthly.iterrows():
                stock_month = i.month
                curr_month = datetime.now().month
                if curr_month == 1:
                    acc_month = 12
                else:
                    acc_month = curr_month-1
                sent_date = i + timedelta(days = 33)
                date_str = sent_date.strftime('%Y-%m')  # Adjust format as needed
                if r['Crossover'] != 'Neutral' and stock_month==acc_month:
                    print('monthly', date_str, stock, r['Crossover'])
                    webhook_discord(webhook_url_monthly, date_str, r['Crossover'], stock, r['Crosspoint'])
                    #pass
                    sleep(5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

tried a few solution offered by gpt and changed numbers in the sent date.

Can you reduce this to a [mre]. If you're just asking about the dates, is all the crossover logic relevant? Or the discord webhook? Just write a simple script that fetches the trading data you want and show that it doesn't return recent data.

Free financial data services are usually delayed, although it's typically 15-30 minutes, not a week.
